# Azure Data Factory v2 and Integration Runtime in different geo datacenters

Tags: azure, networking, ssis, region, azure-data-factory

On the general availability list we may see that "Integration Runtime" feature is generally available in some datacenters where even Azure Data Factory v2 is not yet available (i.e. I really cannot provision it there).

Logically, Azure Data Factory is assumed as a parenting relationship for "Integration Runtime".  Even though I can provision each one of them in different geographical regions.  Does it imply anything? Is there any explicit network communication ongoing between these resources?

I am asking b/c we consider enabling "Integration Runtime" in the regions where ADF v2 itself is not yet generally available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reference [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction#supported-regions)

"However, a data factory can access data stores and compute services in other Azure regions to move data between data stores or process data using compute services.

Azure Data Factory itself does not store any data. It lets you create data-driven workflows to orchestrate the movement of data between supported data stores and the processing of data using compute services in other regions or in an on-premises environment. It also allows you to monitor and manage workflows by using both programmatic and UI mechanisms.

Although Data Factory is available only in certain regions, the service that powers the data movement in Data Factory is available globally in several regions. If a data store is behind a firewall, then a Self-hosted Integration Runtime that's installed in your on-premises environment moves the data instead.

For an example, let's assume that your compute environments such as Azure HDInsight cluster and Azure Machine Learning are running out of the West Europe region. You can create and use an Azure Data Factory instance in East US or East US 2 and use it to schedule jobs on your compute environments in West Europe. It takes a few milliseconds for Data Factory to trigger the job on your compute environment, but the time for running the job on your computing environment does not change."